# Read multiple files from a folder and pass each file through a function in R

Tags: r

```
    filenames <- list.files("foldername", pattern="*.xlsx", full.names=TRUE)
for(file in filenames){

      data_preprocessed <- file %>% 
        group_by(date = floor_date(DATE,"month")) %>%
        summarize(SALES = sum(SALES)) %>%
        separate(date, sep="-", into = c("year", "month")) %>%
        mutate(lag_12 = shift(SALES,-12),
               lag_24 = shift(SALES,-24)) %>% 
        rowwise()
      write_xlsx(data_preprocessed,"file_name.xlsx")
    }
```

All files should be read one after the other and then saved/written(write.xlsx) with a different name.

Comment: this is just defining a function over and over again it looks like. why have you made a function?

Comment: I have made the edit. We could remove the function. The goal is to write the files after passing through the above segment on the code.

Comment: You say you want to save the data with different names. You should change `write_xlsx(data_preprocessed,"file_name.xlsx")` to `write_xlsx(data_preprocessed, paste0(file, ".xlsx"))`, for example. Otherwise each saved file has the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function which

1) Reads the file

2) Performs all the data-processing steps

3) writes the new file

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

f1 <- function(file) {
   readxl::read_xlsx(file) %>%
      group_by(date = floor_date(DATE,"month")) %>%
      summarize(SALES = sum(SALES)) %>%
      separate(date, sep="-", into = c("year", "month")) %>%
      mutate(lag_12 = shift(SALES,-12),
             lag_24 = shift(SALES,-24))  %>%
      writexl::write_xlsx(paste0('new_', basename(file)))    
}
```

and do this for every file.

```
lapply(filenames, f1)
```

Comment: Is it possible to read files out of a folder and then those files are passed through the function without running the above function again manually? We could write a for loop for this maybe.

Comment: The last line `lapply(filenames, f1)` is a loop to run the function `f1` on every `filename`.

Comment: I have set the correct path, but still the apply function shows 'path does not exist'

Comment: Can you check `filenames` , does it have correct full filename path?

Comment: Yes, it's a full filename path of that folder

Comment: Can you check if it give you error on any specific file or all the files? Because it worked fine for me when I tested it on small subset of files.

Comment: it's working now:). There was some error at my end. Code works fine :)